# Passing string parameter in JenkinsFile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm looking to pass `$options` which is a string parameter in my Jenkinsfile. Below is my Jenkinsfile.
I get this error when I run the pipeline: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property '$options' on null object` . What am I missing?

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'babylon_ansible:latest'
      args '-u root'
    }
  } 
    
  stages {
    stage('ansible playbook') {
      steps {
        script {
          withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'babylondumpspwd', variable: 'db_pass')]) {
            sh 'pwd'
            sh 'babylondumps' '$options`
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined `options` variable?

Comment: Have a look to https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Comment: @Melkjot I have it in the job. I selected `project is parameterized` option and added `options` as a string parameter. This doesnt let me paste the screenshot here :(

Comment: @fmdaboville Should we define parameters in the pipeline even if the parameter is already added in the Jenkins job?

Comment: You can define them in the pipeline and they will be added to the jenkins job after the first build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parameter with `params.options` and call `sh` with 
`sh "babylondumps ${params.options}"`